# Consecutive join operations on an Array in a single line of code

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to take a list of links and split them with alternating joins.

Here's what I have:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :011 > tmp = [1,2,3,4,5,6].map(&:to_s)
 => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :012 > tmp2 = []
 => [] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :013 > tmp.each_slice(2) {|a| tmp2 << a.join("\t")}
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :014 > tmp2.join("<br\>")
 => "1\t2<br>3\t4<br>5\t6"
```

Is there a way to do this in a single line?  I know I can do it with a `Proc` or a block call, but I am hoping for something cleaner.  It seems like there is always some `Array` or `Enumerable` method I've yet to learn about, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Why do you need `map` method in :013?

Comment: Ha, I don't, but I was trying to see if I could get an array out of it... and I didn't clean it out of the code.  I'll correct this example.

Comment: Are you wanting it joined by "<br>", or <br\>"?

Comment: Oh, hey, good catch.  <br\> was the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` after `each_slice`, rather than using `<<`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].each_slice(2).map {|a| a.join("\t")}.join("<br\>")
```

Comment: Oh ruby... So beautiful.  I was close.  Thanks!

Comment: You were 30s faster. Didn't see your answer till I posted mine.

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].each_slice(2).map{|d| d.join("\t")}.join("<br/>")
```

Comment: We probably don't need the `.map(&:to_s)` bit.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Thanks for catching that. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = [1,2,3,4,5,6].map(&:to_s)
tmp.map { |i| i.to_i % 2 == 1 ? "#{i}\t" : "#{i}<br>" }.to_s
```

Comment: This puts `"\t"` after 6, which isn't wanted.

Comment: Well you did say alternating.  Just figured I'd give it a shot. : )